# How to handle json response & file both in window.open?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am doing file download using window.open (from React's jsx file):

```
function downloadFile(documentName, event) {
    var response = window.open('/downloadViewDocument/'+ documentName, "_self");
 }
```

And from node/express I am returning the file something like below:

```
 var document = __dirname + "/../../attachments/" + req.params.documentName.trim();
    fs.stat(document, function(err, stat) {
        if(err == null) {
            console.log('File exists');
            res.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + req.params.documentName.trim() + "\"");
            var filestream = fs.createReadStream(document);
            filestream.pipe(res);
        } else if(err.code == 'ENOENT') {
            // file does not exist
            **res.json({success: true, msg: 'File Does Not Exist!'});**
        } else {
            **res.json({success: true, msg: 'Error Occured, Please Try Again!'});**
        }
    });
```

***Please notice that in above code in case of error, I am returning JSON object.*** 
If file is found then it gets downloaded.
 ***But in case if file not found I want to read from msg and want to show proper error message to the user.*** 
***I can't see any option with window.open to read the response back. Is there any other way?***

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way would be to just print the error message with `window.alert()`.

There are tons of other solutions for this, but if I understand your question correctly you just want to print the error message to the client in an easy way.

Comment: Please notice I am not making AJAX call. I am using window.open

Comment: Do I need to make separate ajax call to make sure the file exists or not...and based on that I should call window.open?

Comment: I would absolutely make an Ajax call to check if the file exists or not. If it does return a status 200 and the file exists, then you can do window.open to download the file and window.alert() if you want to print out the corresponding error message.

Comment: Yea But i don't want to make two calls, from client to server for single file download. Can you suggest any other option?

Comment: You don't need to make two calls. Use the advantage of Promises in Javascript (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)